# Annotate a Map in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary, boolean

How to annotate a Map where keys are entity classes, and values normal java Objects (Boolean in my case) in an entity class?

I have two @Entity classes: Voter and Poll.
In the Poll class, I want to keep a Map< Voter,Boolean > of the Voters that can vote on this Poll. Boolean marks whether a Voter has voted or not. So the Mapping is Many-to-many in polls to voters.

I have classes:

```
@Enity
public class Voter {
    ...some attributes and their getters and setters
    private List<Poll> polls;
    private int voterId;

    @Id
    public int getVoterId() {
         return voterId;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="voters")
    public List<Poll> getPolls() {
        return polls;
    }
    ..and setter.
}

@Enity
public class Poll {
    ...some attributes and their getters and setters
    private Map<Voter,Boolean> voters;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="voterId")
    public Map<Voter,Boolean> getVoters() {
        return voters;
    }
    ..and setter.
}
```

This fails when run and causes AnnotationException.
I have seen annotation @MapKeyJoinColumn used, and tried with it as well (instaed of @JoinColumn), and failed. I haven't found an example like this (key of map an entity, value of map just an object) anywhere yet, so I basically used the try-fail way.

So the question is: what annotations should I put where?

Comment: I guess, one problem you have is that your @ManyToMany annotation in the Voter class refers to the field Poll.voters as being the opposite end of this association, which can't be true as voters is not a field of the type Voter. Rename your map to another name, an this error should be fixed. However, this does not solve your map issue.

Answer (score 0):

For a map where the values are basic types (or `Embeddable` types) like `Boolean`, you need to use the [`@ElementCollection` annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html). JPA will create a join table for the `Map`.

However, you cannot reference this collection table with a `@ManyToMany` annotated attribute in the `Voter` class. For this, you can add another `Collection` of `Voter` entities in the `Poll` class.

You can use `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToMany` annotations if you have an entity as the value type. Unfortunately, this is not applicable in your case.